# wordpress category in wp nav menu

Tags: wordpress

I am using wp nav menu to add menus in my wordpress website.`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>`. I have a category named `Events`. I need to include this category in wp nav menu. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Appearance -> Menus
2. If there's no menu created, create one on the main area
3. Select the menu on the "Theme Locations" drop-down in the middle column, and click on "Save".
4. Now scroll down, and on the middle column you'll see a box called "Categories". If the category you need is listed there, check it and click on "Add to menu", if not, click on the "View all" tab first.
5. Click on "save menu".